Was Tara Markov cloned?
In Young Justice season 3 episode 22 Helga Jace describes how she "drowned" Tara Markov in Tar (a fluid designed to activate the meta genes), and recreated her as her as her daughter: the meta human Terra.
Was this meant literally, that Terra was a clone of Tara and that the original Tara was murdered by Jace, or did she mean this figuratively, meaning that Terra and Tara Markov are one-in-the-same person in a physical sense.
I'm using Terra and Tara for convenience. As Tara had not yet taken on codename Terra by the time of this episode.

No, Terra and Tara are one and the same person. Helga meant it figuratively, but she saw the children she activated very much as her own.
From the Terra entry on Fandom:

[Helga Jace] bathed her in Tar to activate her dormant Meta-Gene. As Tara was reborn as a meta-human, Jace felt that she was now the girl's mother, and grew attached to her.

(Notice also that the linked Fandom page is that of Tara Markov, and 'Tara Markov' redirects to this page.)

Fandom is a crowd sourced wiki, these sites are usually dominated by a few users who produce the majority of content, so I'm not really convinced unless they can source it to something official, or at least canonical.

@AaarghZombies I am aware of that, but the fact that it's an extensive, single page for both characters, without any obvious grammatical mistakes at first glance, suggests that there is internal consensus. I'll look for more official sources, nonetheless.

if you look at these fan wiki pages you will find that there are hundreds of characters who are stated to have autism or Asperger, or ADHD, even though the source material makes no mention of these things even existing in-universe. If the fan wiki has a source for these claims then that's different, but until then it's the equivalent of shipping.

You have a point about fan-managed websites not being a definitive source, but just look at the the primary source then. Young Justice has examples of superheroes being cloned and sometimes replaced, and there's no shying away from using the word. When Helga confessed under the influence of the Anti-Life Equation, she does not say cloning is involved and is incapable of hiding it if it were. Rebirth does not usually describe clone replacements either, whether in science fiction or real religious practices. This is one of the many cases where the fan website was right.
